# opencv displaying an image over a video frame (with chessboard) - rotation of the image

Tags: image, opencv, video, rotation

I didn't know what title would correctly describe my problem, I hope this one is not confusing.

I started my adventure with OpenCV a few days ago. Until today I managed to find a chessboard in a live stream from my internet camera and display a resized image on it. My next goal is to make the program rotate the image while I'm rotating the chessboard. Unfortunately I have no idea how to do that, I saw many codes, many examples but none of them helped. My last goal is to do something like this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=APxgPYZOd0I (I can't get anything from his code, he uses Qt, I only met it once and I'm not interested in it - yet).

Here is my code:

```
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

vector<Point3f> Create3DChessboardCorners(Size boardSize, float squareSize);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
Size boardSize(6,9);
float squareSize=1.f;
namedWindow("Viewer");
namedWindow("zdjecie");
namedWindow("changed");

Mat zdjecie=imread("D:\\Studia\\Programy\\cvTest\\Debug\\przyklad.JPG");
resize(zdjecie, zdjecie, Size(200,150));
Mat changed=Mat(zdjecie);
imshow("zdjecie", changed);

vector<Point2f> corners;

VideoCapture video(0);
cout<<"video height: "<<video.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)<<endl;
cout<<"video width: "<<video.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)<<endl;
Mat frame;
bool found;
Point2f src[4];
Point2f dst[4];
Mat perspMat;

while(1)
{
    video>>frame;
    found=findChessboardCorners(frame, boardSize, corners, CALIB_CB_FAST_CHECK);
    changed=Mat(zdjecie);
//      drawChessboardCorners(frame, boardSize, Mat(corners), found);

    if(found)
    {
        line(frame, corners[0], corners[5], Scalar(0,0,255));
        line(frame, corners[0], corners[48], Scalar(0,0,255));
        src[0].x=0;
        src[0].y=0;
        src[1].x=zdjecie.cols;
        src[1].y=0;

        src[2].x=zdjecie.cols;
        src[2].y=zdjecie.rows;
        src[3].x=0;
        src[3].y=zdjecie.rows;

        dst[0].x=corners[0].x;
        dst[0].y=corners[0].y;
        dst[1].x=corners[boardSize.width-1].x;
        dst[1].y=corners[boardSize.width-1].y;

        dst[2].x=corners[boardSize.width*boardSize.height-1].x;
        dst[2].x=corners[boardSize.width*boardSize.height-1].y;
        dst[3].x=corners[boardSize.width*(boardSize.height-1)].x;
        dst[3].y=corners[boardSize.width*(boardSize.height-1)].y;

        perspMat=getPerspectiveTransform(src, dst);
        warpPerspective(zdjecie, changed, perspMat, frame.size());
}
imshow("changed", changed);
            imshow("Viewer", frame);
            if(waitKey(20)!=-1)
            break;
}
return 0;
}
```

I was trying to understand this code: http://dsynflo.blogspot.com/2010/06/simplar-augmented-reality-for-opencv.html
but nothing helped. It didn't even work for me - the image from my webcamera was inverted, frames were changing every few seconds and nothing was being displayed.

So what I ask for is not a whole solution. If someone explained me the way how to do it, I'd be glad. I want to understand it from basics and I just don't know where to go now. I spent much time on trying to solve it, if I didn't, I would not bother you with my problem.

I'm lookin forward for you answers !

Greetings,
Daniel

EDIT:
I changed the code. Now you can see how I try to warp the perspective on my image. Firstly I thought that the reason why after calling warpPerspective function my image Mat changed (it's Mat krzywe, I changed its name so it won't be confusing) is black, is the fact I don't start warping perspective everytime from the basic photo. So I added the line
    changed=Mat(zdjecie)

I guess my problem is pretty simply to solve but I really have no idea now.

Comment: I just compiled your code and I it was able to detect the checkerboard. Can you upload an image of your camera capturing your checkerboard?

Comment: http://img19.imageshack.us/img19/3361/f0tx.jpg it means it captures my chessboard but here is another one, I'm not sure which one you wanted to see. With this picture I added a line of code:

drawChessboardCorners(frame, boardSize, Mat(corners), found);

http://img593.imageshack.us/img593/8872/0ya9.jpg

Comment: Regarding some of the questions: The image is not inverted, but a lot of other apps invert the webcam image to give you the impression of a mirror. So if you also want to have the 'mirror' look you need to invert the image yourself. And the framerate of you program is relatively slow since the search for the checkerboard takes quite some time. So this is also not unusual.

Comment: So what I am seeing is that the chessboard gets detected and you are able to blend in a custom image which probably somehow moves with the chessboard. So what exactly does not work the way you expect it to?

Comment: Firstly: Thanks for telling me about inverting the image, I actually didn't care about such issues - but thanks ;)
Secondly: If you look at the video to which I gave a link, you'll see the the image of a cat displayed on a chessboard. When the guy rotates the chessboard, the image rotates and its perspective is being warped, too. I understand that if I want to warpPerspective, I need to create a matrix by calling perspMat=getPerspectiveTransform(src, dst); After that I can call warpPerspective(zdjecie, krzywe, perspMat, zdjecie.size()); But Mat krzywe after that is a black image. What's wrong?

Comment: Can you post your code for this?

Comment: I changed the code in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see it, there are two problems. First, the coordinates you are warping from and to are wrong. The source coordinates are simply the corners of the source image:

```
    src[0].x=0;
    src[0].y=0;
    src[1].x=zdjecie.cols;
    src[1].y=0;

    src[2].x=zdjecie.cols;
    src[2].y=zdjecie.rows;
    src[3].x=0;
    src[3].y=zdjecie.rows;
```

The destination coordinates must be the corners points of the found chessboard points. Which points are the corner points changes with the size of the chessboard. Since my chessboard had different dimension I tried to make it adaptive by taking the size of the board into account:

```
    dst[0].x=corners[0].x;
    dst[0].y=corners[0].y;
    dst[1].x=corners[ boardSize.width-1 ].x;
    dst[1].y=corners[ boardSize.width-1 ].y;

    dst[2].x=corners[ boardSize.width * boardSize.height - 1 ].x;
    dst[2].y=corners[ boardSize.width * boardSize.height - 1 ].y;
    dst[3].x=corners[ boardSize.width * (boardSize.height-1) ].x;
    dst[3].y=corners[ boardSize.width * (boardSize.height-1) ].y;
```

The second problem is, that you warp into an image that has only the size of the source image. But it needs to have the size of the target image:

```
    warpPerspective(zdjecie, changed, perspMat, frame.size());
```

Another thing I found peculiar is, that our `imshow("Viewer", frame);` call is inside the if-clause. This means, the image is only updated if a chessboard was found. I am not sure, if that was intended.

Now you should have one window showing the video and another window showing the transformed source image. Your next step would now be to blend those both images together.

**Update:**

Here is how I merge the two images:

```
Mat mask = changed > 0;
Mat merged = frame.clone();
changed.copyTo(merged,mask);
```

The `mask` matrix is `true` for all pixels that are not zero in the warped image. Then all non-zero pixels from the warped image are copied into the frame.

Comment: Aight, so I am sorry I did not respond earlier. Of course the imshow function was outside the if statement, I just put the bracket in the wrong place - while copying the code from visual studio to here (I just copy blocks of code cause I got a lot of commented things which I never use). Thank you very very very much for your answer, you helped a lot (actually I really feel bad about the fact I made such stupid mistake with these src and dst points, it shouldn't be a problem for me). Unfortunately what I see after those changes is here: http://img7.imageshack.us/img7/6766/nryd.jpg

Comment: As you look closer, I added two red lines (both beginning in corners[0], just to make sure there is the first found corner). Also when I hold the chessboard upside down the warped image is not that strange as shown in the picture above. What's wrong with that? And last question - blending those two images should be done by some logic operations or is there a ready function?

Comment: Hard to say what exactly the problem is. Could be as simple as a type. Here is the [code](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/445644/ar.cpp) I used. Maybe you can find out whats wrong by comparing it. I will add something in the text above about merging the images.

Comment: Thank you very much for solving this, I'm sure this can be helpful for many people starting with AR in OpenCV. Greetings!